# How can I implement a File Dialog box that opens in Azure Jupyter Notebook In Python?

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel, azure-notebooks

My Code :

```
%gui qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

def gui_fname(dir=None):
    """Select a file via a dialog and return the file name."""
    if dir is None: dir ='./'
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select data file...", 
                dir, filter="All files (*);; SM Files (*.sm)")
    return fname[0]

from IPython.display import display
button = widgets.Button(description="Open The File  !!")
button.style.button_color = 'yellow'
display(button)


def on_button_clicked(b):
    print("Button clicked.")
    f=gui_fname()
    #import fileplot
    #fileplot.load_file(f)



button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
#b1 = Button(description='Open File !!')
#b1.style.button_color = 'yellow'
#b1.on_click(on_button_clicked)
#b1
```

Problem :
It works fine in local pc 
python version 2.7
os Linux

But when i try to implement it remotely in Azure Jupyter Notebook It's kernel dies every time i run the code and i am not able to get the results .
Is there any other way by which i can implement a file dialog box with html5 widgets in ipython widgets ??

What i need 
I need the user to Choose the file that is in His/Her pc which is locally aviable.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can not use any native GUI API on Azure Jupyter Notebook, due to Azure Jupyter Notebook runs on a remote Linux server without any GUI support and it's a web application for remote accessing.

So if you want to show a file dialog box for client user, HTML File dialog is the only option for you. The simple solution is using the `display` & `HTML` class of `IPython` module to show a `Choose File` button, please see the code & result as below.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML("""
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
"""))
```

The result is:

[image]

For more complex cases, you can refer to these blogs [`IPython Notebook: Javascript/Python Bi-directional Communication`](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/) and [`Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to create your own one. However, there is lack a service to receive & save the upload file which need implement by yourself. Or you can simply use an existing project named `fileupload`([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/fileupload/), [GitHub](https://github.com/peteut/ipython-file-upload)) for IPython which is "An IPython notebook widget to upload files, using [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)."

Comment: I have used html but in that i only get the selected file name i want the file path which is not aviable in it . You have any idea how to get the file path ??

Comment: My question is i want to select a file then how will i read it because i am only getting the file name.

Comment: My question After selecting the file
How to read the file in python through pandas ??
it requires file path but it only gave me  file name .